# Accessing int that must be made inside if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, scope, arduino

So I'm working on a project where I use a color sensor. I made a way to define RGB but i need to do something based on if its red green or blue... The 'decision' of whether its red green or blue is made inside of an if statement so how can i access that color outside of it? (R = 1, B =2, G=3 made so its easier to work with)
Or is there another way of doing this?

The overall task is if its red, send 1 beep,
green, 2 beep , same with blue and different combinations of colors that send different amounts of beeps.

Code;

```
int s2 = 7;
int s3 = 8;
int s4 = 4;
int OUTpin= 4;

void setup(){
   pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(4,INPUT);

   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
   //Check Color reads pulse for RGB

   // void checkred
   digitalWrite(s2, LOW);
   digitalWrite(s3, LOW);
   unsigned int RW = 255 - (pulseIn(OUTpin, LOW)/ 400 - 1);  // turns into 0-255
   delay(6000);

   // void checkgreen
   digitalWrite(s2,LOW);
   digitalWrite(s3,HIGH);
   unsigned int GW =  255 - (pulseIn(OUTpin, LOW)/  400 - 1);
   delay(6000);

   // void checkblue
   digitalWrite(s2, HIGH);
   digitalWrite( s3, HIGH);
   unsigned int BW = 255 - (pulseIn(OUTpin, LOW) / 400 - 1);
   delay(6000);

   // seeing which color I got(r g or b)
   if (RW > BW && RW > GW){
      int color = 1;    // used to store that color, that's the 
                        // problem(because its inside if scope)
      delay(7000);
   }  else if  (GW > RW && GW > BW){
      int color = 2;
      delay(7000);
   } else if  (BW > RW && BW > GW){
      int color = 3;
      delay(7000);
   } 
}
```

Comment: "int that must be inside if statement" -- _why_?

Comment: im seeing whichever of the rgb is higher determines which color it sensed. So its kinda if red is bigger than blue, its red..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not declare it outside the if-else if ladder and set its value in the conditions?
Something like,

```
    int i;
    if(...)
    {
      i=1;
    }
    else if(...)
    { 
      i=2;
    }
```

...and so

Comment: Why not? For example because there's no way to make `i` a `const` variable.

Comment: you should also assign the variable a default value in case none of the conditions match or keep an else statement.

Comment: It is *usually* desirable to make variables `const`. A solution like this prevents that. Coincidentally, Java has a syntax to make it work with `final`  variables. However, in C++, you have to initialise a `const` variable immediately.

Comment: yeah,you are absolutely correct but in the case of this particular question there wasn't a requirement of a const

Answer (score 2):

Declare `color` before the if statement, and just assign to it in the blocks:

```
// seeing which color I got(r g or b)
int color = 0;
if (RW > BW && RW > GW){
  color = 1;    // no `int` here, just assigning
    delay(7000);
}  else if  (GW > RW && GW > BW){
  color = 2;
  delay(7000);
} else if  (BW > RW && BW > GW){
  color = 3;
  delay(7000);
}
```

If you need it to survive to a future call to loop, make it global.

Comment: intialize it to a sentinel value too, so you won't mistakenly apply something incorrectly.

Comment: agreed.. only one problem if all values R G B are the same (a grey color) the value of color will not be initialize and could be anything.. so set it to 1,2, or 3 which ever is your default in that case or -1 and test for that before you use it :).

Comment: @Chad:  yes, I should have initialized it.  Edited.  I missed that the final `else` was an `else if`.

Answer (score 1):

A very clean solution would be to move that functionality into a separate function which returns an `int`. This is also the only way to make the resulting `int` a `const` variable, which is good practice.

Example:

```
int ChooseColor(unsigned int RW, unsigned int BW, unsigned int GW)
{
    // seeing which color I got(r g or b)
    if (RW > BW && RW > GW) {
        return 1;
    } else if  (GW > RW && GW > BW) {
        return 2;
    } else if  (BW > RW && BW > GW) {
        return 3;
    }
    assert(false);
    return 0; // to prevent compiler warnings
}
```

Then inside `loop`, do this:

```
int const color = ChooseColor(RW, BW, GW);
delay(7000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `int` outside the if statements. The reason you couldn't access them was because they were local variable of the `if` statement. Thus, once the `if` ended, all variables declared inside of it, including your `int` will be destroyed.

You might sometimes use this to your advantage, such as for memory management, but for today, the short answer is to simply make the `int` outside and to give it a value in the `if`.